# Why does renaming this MSpec class through ReSharper break the test runner?

Tags: c#, resharper, mspec

I have problems renaming MSpec test classes using ReSharper's "rename" refactoring. For example:

```
[Subject("Move to first page")]
public class When_possible { }
```

When I rename it to `When_in_second_page` and click the run test icon on the left side, I see an incorrect rename, "When in second" and the test doesn't run!

[image: bad resharper rename]

Sometimes the left icons are gone all together. Build or Rebuild doesn't fix it, but a restart does. I've had other [MSpec problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17510045/2556111), do you think they're related? or an installation related problem?

Comment: Have you cleaned your code, then Rebuild?

Comment: Yes, not only project but also solution

Comment: I update mspec to 0.5.14 (was 0.5.12) but the problem remains.

Comment: This is definitely a problem with the runner. This thing is haunting me since forever. Please file a bug report on GitHub, linking to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues at various times where the R# test runner seems to get out of sync with the code. Here are some things that I've tried at various times that have helped. To be fair, this probably isn't an MSpec issue, it seems more likely related to the R# test runner (whether the R# part or the MSpec part, I don't know).

Anyway, try the following:

- Have you tried setting your build settings (in the R# test runner window) to 'auto'?
- What about disabling shadow-copying of assemblies in the R# unit test options?
- Check that all of your assemblies (and dependencies) are targeting the same version of .NET. I do a lot of work targeting .NET 3.5 and I'm always getting new projects that are set to 4.5 by default. I've found that this can really confuse R# and/or MSpec.
- Close all the R# test sessions and let it start with a new, clean session.

Comment: All my settings are as you suggested, except shadow-copying. I Will disable it and test. After the problem show up, close and start a new session does not fix it.

Comment: After disable shadow-copy the problem continues to arise